# Python, dataframes : duplicating elements in a column of lists and attributing to them rows in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to duplicate a line of a dataframe to as much as elements I have in its first colulmn.

I have the following dataframe:

```
     columns_A           columns_B
0    [1,2,3,4]           ['bob', 'mary']
1    [7,9]               ['banana', 'apple']
```

And I want as a result :

```
     columns_A            columns_B
0    1                   ['bob', 'mary']
1    2                   ['bob', 'mary']
2    3                   ['bob', 'mary']
3    4                   ['bob', 'mary']
4    7                   ['banana', 'apple']
5    9                   ['banana', 'apple']
```

For now I can access the list of column_A but I can't assign to every element the corresponding list in column_B.
The folowing code get me the first row of column_B to all elements. I dont know how to attribute the row according to the location of line1 in column_A.

```
for line1 in df.column_A:
    for i in line1:
        s= {i : df.column_B[0]} 
        print s
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeat values by legths by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and flat values of nested `lists` by `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "columns_B": np.repeat(df.columns_B.values, df.columns_A.str.len()),
        "columns_A": list(chain.from_iterable(df.columns_A))})

print (df2)
   columns_A        columns_B
0          1      [bob, mary]
1          2      [bob, mary]
2          3      [bob, mary]
3          4      [bob, mary]
4          7  [banana, apple]
5          9  [banana, apple]
```

Pure pandas solution is [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `Series` created by `DataFrame` constructor and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.stack.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns_A.values.tolist())
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .astype(int)
        .rename('columns_A')
print (df2)
0    1
0    2
0    3
0    4
1    7
1    9
Name: columns_A, dtype: int32

print (df.drop('columns_A', axis=1).join(df2).reset_index(drop=True))
         columns_B  columns_A
0      [bob, mary]          1
1      [bob, mary]          2
2      [bob, mary]          3
3      [bob, mary]          4
4  [banana, apple]          7
5  [banana, apple]          9
```

Answer (score 3):

using `pd.melt`

```
a, b = df
pd.melt(
    df.drop(a, 1).join(df[a].apply(pd.Series)),
    b, [0, 1, 2, 3], value_name=a
).dropna()[df.columns.tolist()].astype(df.dtypes) \
 .sort_values(b, ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

  columns_A        columns_B
0         1      [bob, mary]
1         2      [bob, mary]
2         3      [bob, mary]
3         4      [bob, mary]
4         7  [banana, apple]
5         9  [banana, apple]
```

Comment: Nice stuff. If I just follow you around, I will become an expert in Pandas  =)